# Read and write in C# buffer in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, interview-questions, thread-safety

I have a buffer - `int` array with defined length. I want to read and write values into this array in parallel. For instance, 5 readers and 3 writers with different intervals. Additionally, I want to block waiting readers and waiting writers until a specific operation (read or write) is available.

Buffer:

```
public class IntBuffer
{
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _readDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _writeDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private readonly int[] _array;
    private int _index;

    public IntBuffer(int bufferSize)
    {
        _array = new int[bufferSize];
        _index = -1;
    }

    public void Write(int insert)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_index >= -1 && _index < _array.Length - 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    Monitor.Enter(this);

                    if (_index >= -1 && _index < _array.Length - 1)
                    {
                        _array[++_index] = insert;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(this);
                    _readDone.Set();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("waiting for add...");
            _writeDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }

    public int Read()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_index >= 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Monitor.Enter(this);
                    if (_index >= 0)
                    {
                        var val = _array[_index--];
                        return val;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(this);
                    _writeDone.Set();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("waiting for read...");
            _readDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Reader:

```
public class Reader
{
    private readonly IntBuffer _buff;

    public Reader(IntBuffer buff)
    {
        _buff = buff;
    }

    public void Start(int sleepMs)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(sleepMs);
            Console.WriteLine($"reader read {_buff.Read()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Writer:

```
public class Writer
{
    private readonly IntBuffer _buff;
    private readonly Random _random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

    public Writer(IntBuffer buff)
    {
        _buff = buff;
    }

    public void Start(int sleepMs)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(sleepMs);
            int val = _random.Next(1, 500);
            _buff.Write(val);
            Console.WriteLine($"writer write {val}");
        }
    }
}
```

All in one:

```
var buffer = new IntBuffer(8);

new Thread(() => new Writer(buffer).Start(1700)).Start();
new Thread(() => new Writer(buffer).Start(2900)).Start();
new Thread(() => new Writer(buffer).Start(3450)).Start();

new Thread(() => new Reader(buffer).Start(5000)).Start();
new Thread(() => new Reader(buffer).Start(3000)).Start();
new Thread(() => new Reader(buffer).Start(1400)).Start();
```

Please review and add remarks.

Comment: May I ask what the real application is used for?

Comment: @Paparazzi Actually it's an interview excercise.

Comment: Can you not use TPL?  There is already a DataFlowBlock that will do exactly what is asked

Comment: `AutoResetEvent` implements `IDisposable`, so your class`IntBuffer` should as well and both of those should be disposed of in the `Dispose()` method. Further, `Reader` and `Writer` will then have references to `IntBuffer`, so *they* should implement `IDisposable` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to archive is very similar to the [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Note that you can look at the .net framework's [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,3fc8b6e4e28ee36c) to get an idea how to implement it professionally ;).

The overall implementation seems to work and I think the blocking mechanism does what it is supposed to.

However, some points to note:

- Do not use the instance of the buffer as synchronization object (`Monitor.Enter(this)`;) because the object can be locked by someone else from outside... Create a private sync object instead.
- In method `Read`, the temporary variable `val` is not required - just return the value.
- I would rename the class to make clear, that the call of `Write` may block the current thread (maybe BlockingBuffer, BlockingStack or something like that).
- Why not making the class generic?